# how to reply of an email in imap yii2

Tags: php, email, yii2, gmail-imap, reply

i'm facing the problem that when i send reply message it appears as a new mail in my mailbox...i want to send an email in a reply.. can anyone help me regarding this?

```php
public function Reply($id)
{
    $data = $this->findModel($id);

    if($data->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $data->save()) {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom($data->from_email)
            ->setTo($data->to_email)
            ->setSubject("Re :" . $data->subject)
            ->setTextBody($data->reply)
            ->send();
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $data,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a feature of imap protocol at all? I was under impression that this is the feature of mail clients that can mark replies like that. I'm not sure though

Comment: You need to add `In-Reply-To` and/or `References` headers.

Comment: can you provide an implementation code that can help me to solve this problem?